# How can i do to set the image to the middle left, accorded to my 3 paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Here is the **HTML** i'm in a table but i just want for each row of my table, the image to be at the left middle and my 3 paragraph in the middle of the row, the image has to be aligned with text.
in the present code the image is at the left but in the line between "Nom" and "Type" so it's not aligned

```html
<div class="my-container">
      <div class="constrained">
          <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-container="'.constrained'">
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo: packetIndex + packetSize" ng-click="preview(item[0])" ng-class="{active: item[0].selected}">
                <td>
                  <p class="file-name" title="Cliquez pour visualiser le fichier"></p>
                  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download-alt dl-file" style="margin-right:5px" title="Télécharger le fichier" ng-if="item.file === 1"></i>
                  <p style="text-align: center">Nom: <strong>{{ item[0].name }}</strong></p>
                  <p><img ng-src="{{urlConstruc(item[0].kid)}}" alt=" "><p style="text-align: center">Type: <strong>{{ class[item[0].isa].name }}</strong></p>
                  <p style="text-align: center">Date: <strong>{{ item[0].date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</strong></p>
               </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my post here's the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I also created jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/afu16g9k/4/#&togetherjs=5U562O7acI

```
<table width=500>
<tr>
<td align="left">
<img src="https://cdn.vox- cdn.com/thumbor/7fboRS8AmuMpmYvgRBlyOuwhipM=/0x0:1000x750/1200x800/filters:focal(0x0:1000x750)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49579581/mobile-magic_chanpipatshutterstock.0.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=" " align="left">
<span style="text-align:left">  
<p style="text-align: ">Nom: <strong>{{ item[0].name }}</strong></p>    
    <p style="text-align: ">Type: <strong>{{ class[item[0].isa].name }}</strong></p>
    <p style="text-align: ">Date: <strong>{{ item[0].date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} 
</strong></p>
<span>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how can i do if i want the image to be at the left of the text but aligned to type ?

Comment: @SendoTks, I didn't get you. could you plz explain a bit ?

Comment: i finally found how to do i've juste put my image balise IN the <p></p> type paragraphe with an attribute class="pull-left" for the image 
a screen if i'm not clear [link]https://www.zupimages.net/up/18/24/zrk8.png

Answer (score 1):

Use `Flexbox` like this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.abc {
  width: 80%;
}

img {
  width: 20%;
}

.abc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="constrained">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-container="'.constrained'">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo: packetIndex + packetSize" ng-click="preview(item[0])" ng-class="{active: item[0].selected}">
          <td>
            <div class="container">

              <img ng-src="{{urlConstruc(item[0].kid)}}" alt=" ">
              <div class="abc">
                <p style="text-align: center">Nom: <strong>{{ item[0].name }}</strong></p>

                <p style="text-align: center">Type: <strong>{{ class[item[0].isa].name }}</strong></p>
                <p style="text-align: center">Date: <strong>{{ item[0].date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</strong></p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```